# How to get an entity and a count in the same query?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've created the following repository and method. The method does what you would expect it to do except for one thing. It cannot return both `->select('ol')` and `->select('count(ol.product) as totalProducts')`. As soon as I inclode the `->select('ol')` it will ignore the count.

```
class OrderLineRepository
{
    // ...

    public function getOpenOrders()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('ol');
        $orders = $qb
                ->select('count(ol.product) as totalProducts')
                ->select('ol')
                ->where('BIT_AND(ol.flags, 3) = 2')
                ->groupBy('ol.orderId')
                ->setMaxResults(100)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult()
            ;

            return $orders;
    }

    // ...
}
```

I am still in the early stages of mastering symfony and this could possibly quite a stupid question. But it's still a question I'm currently facing. Can someone help me out?

#### Update

Witht the help of RiggsFolly I now get the following result by using `->addSelect(...)` instead of `->select(...)`.

```
array:10 [
    // ...
    array:2 [
        0 => OrderLine {
            id: 8068005
            product: Product {#1503 ▶}
            supplier: Supplier {#1552 ▶}
            reference: Reference {#1528 ▶}
        }
        "products" => "3"
    ]
    // ...
]
```

Ideally, I would like to get it like this:

```
array:10 [
    // ...
    array:2 [
        id: 8068005
        product: Product {#1503 ▶}
        supplier: Supplier {#1552 ▶}
        reference: Reference {#1528 ▶}
        "products" => "3"
    ]
    // ...
]
```

Comment: Try `->addSelect('ol')` to add to the select created by the previous `->select()`

Comment: @RiggsFolly That seems to do the trick. However, it now puts the entity in a subarray in the result. Can this be overcome?

Comment: Of course you could just count the orders using `count($orders)` instead of putting the count on the query

Comment: I am aiming for an array with orders and would like to know how much products each order has.

Comment: You should instead just make your query to get ol, and then do the counting in PHP

Comment: This is one of the limits of the Doctrine ORM (not really Symfony).  Break these out into their own query or if you have a bunch of similar ones then don't use the orm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how it's related OrderLine and Products if it is; but maybe you can create a DB relation between it, so you would get an array of products related to your OrderLine.

Finally, to get the number of products:

```
$productsNumber = count($orderLine->getProducts());
```

**UPDATE**

In this case, total Products will be the same as total OrderLines, is that correct?

So... total products is **not** an OrderLine attribute, in my opinion; and it should not be part of your OrderLine object, instead, you probably can count the OrderLines objects retrieved by Doctrine, and it will be your totalProduct.

Looking a little further, you can also create an `Order` entity, that is related to your `OrderLine` object (One to Many). Then, you could query for your Order entity using Doctrine, and count the `OrderLines` attribute of your `Order` entity, which will be the same as the total products.

Comment: The relationship is slightly different. Every OrderLine has one Product. All OrderLines grouped together represent one order.

Comment: You are totally right. However, I'm working with an existing db structure. But it seems I have no other option than to add an Order entity.